# Trouble formatting a Portfolio Gallery

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a portfolio page, using images as placeholders until I have deployed projects to fill those slots. I am running into trouble trying to format one large image with two - four smaller images below it all filling a container equally.

I've tried the W3 Schools How To's on Image Grids, Responsive Image Grids and Portfolio Gallery's to no avail.

Here is the section of code in question:

```css
.content-section {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.content-section div {
  border-left: 3px solid gray;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content-section h2 {
  width: 15%;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.yoga img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid steelblue;
}
```

```html
<section id="my-work" class="content-section">
  <h2>Work</h2>
  <div class="yoga">
    <img src="img\yoga.jpg" alt="Yoga Project">
  </div>
</section>
```

The problem arises when I try to add other images. The border between h2 and the images either moves or duplicates next to the new images.

I hope this is an appropriate question, I went over the rules before posting. Any help would be very appreciated, if someone can help point me in the right direction! I've linked the deployed website as well.

Thank you!!

https://tnoonan88.github.io/Portfolio-Page/

Comment: Hey! Can you please go over what you're trying to achieve? I don't see anything wrong with the github pages link that you just posted

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I've pushed all my latest commits to github that better show what I'm trying to accomplish. I want the first image "snow report" to have a width of 100%, and then the 2 following images to have both have a width of 50% below the first image. I guess with padding they will probably have a width of less than 50%?

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-shrink. Also, you need a CSS design system to resize your image before positioning them.

> The flex-shrink CSS property sets the flex shrink factor of a flex item. If the size of all flex items is larger than the flex container, items shrink to fit according to flex-shrink.

Answer (score 0):

:) You could use a flex box to solve this issue. So this is what you'd have to do.

1. Update `index.html`

```html
 <div class="flex-container">
   <img class="img1" src="img/snow.jpg?raw=true" alt="Snow Report">
   <div class="flex-container-sub">
     <img src="img/trail-running.jpg?raw=true" alt="Yoga Project">
     <img src="img/yoga.jpg?raw=true" alt="Trail Finder">
   </div>
 </div>
```

2. Update `style.css`

```css
.flex-container-sub {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: 'space-between';
}

.flex-container-sub img:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.flex-container-sub img:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.content-section .flex-container {
  border-left: 3px solid gray;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

> I also remove the `div` selector from content-section cause if you have that, any div inside it will have the border-left property and I'm assuming you don't want that. But this isn't the issue here.

So what I'm doing is, I've added the 2 images that you want below your bigger image into a div. The div has its display as flex and justify-content as `space-between` to space them out evenly. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

The `nth-child` selectors are for selecting the images to give them padding. The cool thing about using a flex box is that the width is taken care of when you add padding. So I'm selecting the first image (`nth-child(1))`, giving it a width of 50%, and a padding top. Next, I'm selecting the second image (`nth-child(2))` and doing the same, but adding a padding to the left. Alternatively, you can add separate classes to these images and do it too!

Here's the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/to6gzqem/28/